# how get all routes in my rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

can I get all routes in my rails application? I need an output like `rake routes` and put the result in an array.

Is it possible? how?

Comment: Where do you need this output?

Comment: For Rails 3 : `Rails.application.routes.routes.to_a` (see [my original answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10576105/407213))

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could have a look at way rails spits out those routes from the rake task. It's in `/gems/rails/2.3.x/lib/tasks/routes.rake` for Rails 2. Seems to be basically doing `ActionController::Routing::Routes.routes` in the general case and then interrogating that.

Comment: For Rails 4 it is now in the railties gem

Comment: thank you @Shadwell - do you know how I could access that?

Comment: Very, very old answer this. You might have some luck here : https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/commands/routes/routes_command.rb

Answer (score 8):

Well, independently of where you need it, you could do:

```
routes = `rake routes`.split("\n")
```

Or even:

```
routes = `rake routes`.split("\n").map{ |r| r.gsub(', ', ',').split(' ') }
```

Answer (score 6):

In order to spread the headache that it was to acomplish that, i did this based on @jordini answer:

```
 Rails.application.routes.routes.to_a.each do |rota|
   if rota.app.instance_variable_defined? '@defaults'
      perm = Permission.where({
        :acao => rota.defaults[:action],
        :controller => rota.defaults[:controller], 
        :verbo => rota.verb.source.to_s.gsub("^","").gsub("$","").downcase
      ).first_or_create
    end
 end
```

This was what i've used to create all permissions for my web page at once.