# Rails string manipulation with routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, string, rake

I have an app where users can register their own personal url like so

- myapp.com/users-personal-url

I want to run through my rails config file and automatically grab the urls that are already in use, and iterate through these in a validation method to prevent users from reserving these urls.  For example...

if in my routes file I have something like

```
match 'test' => 'courses#test'
resource :users
```

then users should not be able to register the "users" url or "test" url.  So far I've found that I can grab all the routes inside a ruby class by using `rake routes`

But my string manipulation skills are failing me since I am a rails noob.  Basically I need to substring the routes, place them in a collection and do the validation check.  A pointer in the right direction or working code is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Traditionally, tildes were prefixed to usernames in URLs, and that would avoid the problem you are facing.  e.g. http://uni.uiuc.edu/~dgrayson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any quick Rails way of doing what you would like to do in the routes.rb.

You would need to create [custom validators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations) in your model.

In the model that handles user generated URL submissions, add this validator.

```
class Whatevermodel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :protect_reserved_url, :on => create

  def protect_reserved_url
    reserved_url = ['test', 'users', 'whatever_other_url_you_want_to_protect']
    if reserved_url.include?(url_submission.downcase)
      errors.add(:url_submission, "is an invalid URL")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well to simply get the routes so that you can match them, this guy had a cool way of doing that [how get all routes in my rails application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672554/how-get-all-routes-in-my-rails-application)

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672554/how-get-all-routes-in-my-rails-application
```

Or you could break them down with

```
Rails.application.routes
```