# How to check if all pages respond successfully

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a quick way to check if all my Rails routes respond successfully?
Even for logged pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [rspec to test your controllers](http://everydayrails.com/2012/04/07/testing-series-rspec-controllers.html)

You can use [ActionController::Routing::Routes.routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672554/how-get-all-routes-in-my-rails-application) to get your routes, use `each` block and use `get` for each route. you need to pass some `params` in some routes.